# Counting the average of intervals in mySQL

Tags: mysql

Say, I have a table that I derived in mySQL:

| doctor | patient_of_doctor | patient_bought_item_from_doctor_x_days_ago |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aaron | Jeff | 10 |
| Aaron | Jeff | 20 |
| Jess | Jason | 50 |
| Jess | Jason | 20 |
| Jess | Jason | 30 |
| Aaron | Stu | 90 |
| Aaron | Stu | 70 |
| Aaron | Stu | 110 |
| Aaron | Stu | 105 |

Now, I would want to make a new table from this one such that for each doctor, the patient's average buy interval is shown.

For this table,

Jeff bought from Aaron 10 and 20 days ago. Jeff's average buy interval is therefore, (20-10)/1 = 10.

Jason bought from Jess 20, 50 and 30 days ago. Jason's average buy interval is ((50-30)+(30-20))/2 = 15.

Stu bought from Aaron 90, 70, 110 and 105 days ago. Stu's average buy interval is ((110-105)+(105-90)+(90-70))/3 = (5+15+20)/3 =40/3 = 13.33

I would want to output a table that looks like this:

| doctor | patient_of_doctor | avg_buy_interval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aaron | Jeff | 10 |
| Jess | Jason | 15 |
| Aaron | Stu | 13.33 |

I am seriously considering using python to do this but I could not pass up the chance to learn some mySQL from you guys.

Thanks!
Umesh

Comment: what have you tried? show us your query. By the way _"Stu bought from Jess .."_ that's suppose to be _"Stu bought from Aaron .."_ , right?

Comment: Yeah, I changed that just now. Thank you!
I have not tried anything to be honest. I do not know where to start with this query.

Comment: I see.. will it be hard to achieve this in Python?

Comment: I will try doing it in python today. Thanks FanoFN!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MySQL v8 (you can run `SELECT version();` to check), you may try using either [LEAD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) or [LAG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) functions to get the previous or next `x_days_ago`. Then you can use `AVG()` on the subtraction result between the current row data with its previous or next `x_days_ago`.

With `LEAD()`:

```
SELECT doctor,
       patient,
       AVG(bxd-prev_data)
 FROM
(SELECT doctor,
       patient,
       bought_x_days_ago AS bxd,
       LEAD(bought_x_days_ago) /*using LEAD*/
             OVER (PARTITION BY doctor, patient 
                    ORDER BY bought_x_days_ago DESC) AS prev_data
  FROM                        /*with ORDER BY in descending*/
    mytable) v
 WHERE prev_data IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY doctor,
          patient;
```

With `LAG()`:

```
SELECT doctor,
       patient,
       AVG(bxd-prev_data)
 FROM
(SELECT doctor,
       patient,
       bought_x_days_ago AS bxd,
       LAG(bought_x_days_ago) /*using LAG*/
             OVER (PARTITION BY doctor, patient 
                    ORDER BY bought_x_days_ago) AS prev_data
  FROM                     /*with ORDER BY in ascending (default)*/
    mytable) v
 WHERE prev_data IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY doctor,
          patient
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f137bd2c932472770d795f9e9d0787e1)

On older MySQL version, you can try this:

```
SELECT doctor,
       patient,
       AVG(prev_bxd-bxd)
  FROM
(SELECT m1.doctor, m1.patient, m1.bought_x_days_ago AS bxd,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      GROUP_CONCAT(m2.bought_x_days_ago ORDER BY m2.bought_x_days_ago),',',1) AS prev_bxd
FROM mytable m1
  LEFT JOIN mytable m2
  ON m1.doctor=m2.doctor
   AND m1.patient=m2.patient
   AND m1.bought_x_days_ago < m2.bought_x_days_ago
GROUP BY
  m1.doctor,
  m1.patient,
  m1.bought_x_days_ago) v
  GROUP BY doctor,
           patient;
```

I'll try to explain it the best I can. The first component here is the table's self `LEFT JOIN`. The condition placed for the join is to match `doctor` and `patient` data exactly and to match the second table `bought_x_days_ago` that is larger from the reference table value. In the `SELECT` section, we're using `GROUP_CONCAT()` over `bought_x_days_ago` from the second table with default ascending order and use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to  get the first value from the `GROUP_CONCAT()` result. Without the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`, the result look like this:

| doctor | patient | bxd | prev_bxd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aaron | Jeff | 10 | 20 |
| Aaron | Jeff | 20 | NULL |
| Aaron | Stu | 70 | 90,105,110 |
| Aaron | Stu | 90 | 105,110 |
| Aaron | Stu | 105 | 110 |
| Aaron | Stu | 110 | NULL |
| Jess | Jason | 20 | 30,50 |
| Jess | Jason | 30 | 50 |
| Jess | Jason | 50 | NULL |

Then with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`, it becomes like this:

| doctor | patient | bxd | prev_bxd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aaron | Jeff | 10 | 20 |
| Aaron | Jeff | 20 | NULL |
| Aaron | Stu | 70 | 90 |
| Aaron | Stu | 90 | 105 |
| Aaron | Stu | 105 | 110 |
| Aaron | Stu | 110 | NULL |
| Jess | Jason | 20 | 30 |
| Jess | Jason | 30 | 50 |
| Jess | Jason | 50 | NULL |

The next step is simple, just make that as a subquery then do the average calculation.

[Here's a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=bab58da5bf276691e8ddd83caf26f6fc)

Comment: Hello FanoFN, thank you for making this effort. Clicking your link proves that the code works. Unfortunately, however, I am using 5.6.36 version for mySQL workbench and unfortunately, OVER and LAG are not recognized as valid commands. I will upvote the answer because it answers the question and I hope this is helpful to anyone who runs into the same problem as me.

Comment: That is a bit unfortunate. There's a way to emulate this in older MySQL version but I reckon it's not as easy as using LEAD() or LAG() though. I'll try a few ways and I found a possible solution, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To do That You should use the group by clause in `sql` which will be somethin like this:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table_name
WHERE [ conditions ]
GROUP BY column1, column2
ORDER BY column1, column2
```

which in your case would be this EXACT SQL Code:

```
SELECT  doctor,
        patient_of_doctor,
        AVG(bought_item) as 'avg_buy_interval'
FROM Patients
GROUP BY doctor, patient_of_doctor
```

and you will have thi result:

[The result of query above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndbq9.png)

Comment: Hey Mohammad, thank you for trying but I am not asking for the average of the third column. I am asking for the average of the intervals in the third column. Please read the explanation in the space between the 2 tables.